# VBA Coloring Bar Charts Based on Cell Color

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to color a Bar Chart based on the Cell Color. I was able to get it to color the first series in the bar chart, but am struggling with getting it to iterate to pull colors from Range B5:B25, and then apply these colors to the different series in the bar chart. The Bar Chart does not always have the same number of series (can go up to B25). I would appreciate any guidance on how to iterate this properly.

[image]

```
Sub ColorAnItem()

Dim c As Range
Dim chrt As Chart

For Each c In Range("B5:B25")
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
    Set chrt = ActiveChart

    ActiveSheet.Cells(c).Select
    clr = ActiveSheet.Cells(c).Interior.Color
                r = clr Mod 256
                g = clr \ 256 Mod 256
                b = clr \ 65536 Mod 256
    chrt.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(r, g, b)
    
 Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```vba
Sub ColorAnItem()

    Dim i As Long, rng As Range, chrt As Chart
    
    Set chrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B5:B25")
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
        
        chrt.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                    rng.Cells(i).Interior.Color
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am getting a Run-time Error '13' Type mismatch for:thechrt.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor = _
                    rng.cells(i).interior.color

Comment: Was missing `RGB` after `ForeColor`.  Tested and working for me.